# Linux CFS how to select the next process

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

I read this book

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Kernel-Architecture-Wolfgang-Mauerer/dp/0470343435](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470343435)

Now i study scheduler，linux kernel now using CFS for normal process

But this book sometime say ,scheduler will choose the wait time longest

process in runqueue to run and sometime say scheduler will choose the vruntime

smallest in runqueue

Which is correct??

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct - both say the same thing in different words.

**To pick up the next process, the scheduler selects the task that has the minimal vruntime. Namely, the process that run the least.**

A process accumulates vruntime only while it is running. So by picking the task that has the minimal vruntime we pick the task that run the least.
On the other hand, a process that waits a lot - does not accumulate vruntime. Therefore its vruntime is low. And if its wait time is the longest- its vruntime will be the lowest - and it will be picked to run next.

Just different ways to say the same thing.